# Computing a single element of the adjugate or inverse of a symbolic binary matrix

Tags: matrix, binary, sympy, sparse-matrix, inverse

I'm trying to get a single element of an adjugate `A_adj` of a matrix `A`, both of which need to be symbolic expressions, where the symbols `x_i` are binary and the matrix `A` is symmetric and sparse. Python's `sympy` works great for small problems:

```
from sympy import zeros, symbols

size = 4
A = zeros(size,size)
x_i = [x for x in symbols(f'x0:{size}')]

for i in range(size-1):
    A[i,i] += 0.5*x_i[i]
    A[i+1,i+1] += 0.5*x_i[i]
    A[i,i+1] = A[i+1,i] = -0.3*(i+1)*x_i[i]

A_adj_0 = A[1:,1:].det()

A_adj_0
```

This calculates the first element `A_adj_0` of the cofactor matrix (which is the corresponding [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra))) and correctly gives me 0.125x_0x_1x_2 - 0.28x_2x_2^2 - 0.055x_1^2x_2 - 0.28x_1x_2^2, which is the expression I need, but there are two issues:

1. This is completely unfeasible for larger matrices (I need this for `size`s of ~100).
2. The `x_i` are binary variables (i.e. either 0 or 1) and there seems to be no way for `sympy` to simplify expressions of binary variables, i.e. simplifying polynomials x_i^n = x_i.

The first issue can be partly addressed by instead solving a linear equation system `Ay = b`, where `b` is set to the first basis vector `[1, 0, 0, 0]`, such that `y` is the first column of the inverse of `A`. The first entry of `y` is the first element of the inverse of `A`:

```
b = zeros(size,1)
b[0] = 1

y = A.LUsolve(b)

s = {x_i[i]: 1 for i in range(size)}

print(y[0].subs(s) * A.subs(s).det())
print(A_adj_0.subs(s))
```

The problem here is that the expression for the first element of `y` is extremely complicated, even after using `simplify()` and so on. It would be a very simple expression with simplification of binary expressions as mentioned in point 2 above. It's a faster method, but still unfeasible for larger matrices.

This boils down to my actual question:

Is there an efficient way to compute a single element of the adjugate of a sparse and symmetric symbolic matrix, where the symbols are binary values?

I'm open to using other software as well.

Addendum 1:
It seems simplifying binary expressions in `sympy` is possible with a simple custom substitution which I wasn't aware of:

```
A_subs = A_adj_0

for i in range(size):
    A_subs = A_subs.subs(x_i[i]*x_i[i], x_i[i])

A_subs
```

Comment: These are great hints, thanks! This will surely be a problem that turns up further down the line, but unfortunately in my current problem the coefficients are real. Hence, if I understand this correctly, the computation cannot be done over finite fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure to use Rational rather than floats in sympy so `S(1)/2` or `Rational(1, 2)` rather than `0.5`.

There is a new (undocumented and for the moment internal) implementation of matrices in sympy called DomainMatrix. It is likely to be a lot faster for a problem like this and always produces polynomial results in a fully expanded form. I expect that it will be much faster for this kind of problem but it still seems to be fairly slow for this because is is not sparse internally (yet - that will probably change in the next release) and it does not take advantage of the simplification from the symbols being binary-valued. It can be made to work over `GF(2)` but not with symbols that are assumed to be in `GF(2)` which is something different.

In case it is helpful though this is how you would use it in sympy 1.7.1:

```
from sympy import zeros, symbols, Rational
from sympy.polys.domainmatrix import DomainMatrix


size = 10
A = zeros(size,size)
x_i = [x for x in symbols(f'x0:{size}')]

for i in range(size-1):
    A[i,i] += Rational(1, 2)*x_i[i]
    A[i+1,i+1] += Rational(1, 2)*x_i[i]
    A[i,i+1] = A[i+1,i] = -Rational(3, 10)*(i+1)*x_i[i]

# Convert to DomainMatrix:
dM = DomainMatrix.from_list_sympy(size-1, size-1, A[1:, 1:].tolist())

# Compute determinant and convert back to normal sympy expression:
# Could also use dM.det().as_expr() although it might be slower
A_adj_0 = dM.charpoly()[-1].as_expr()

# Reduce powers:
A_adj_0 = A_adj_0.replace(lambda e: e.is_Pow, lambda e: e.args[0])

print(A_adj_0)
```

Comment: I just tested this on a larger problem with the real values, and it looks like it works and MUCH faster so than the other methods. This is nothing short of magic. I cannot understate my appreciation for your time. Thank you!